# Not able to load wordpress post content fully in webview in wordpress app on API Level 29. But it works fine on API Level 26

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-webview, androidx

I'm developing WordPress app which fetches post from Wordpress site & loads it in webview. I'm using "WP REST API" (fetch post data in JSON) & retrofit library. In `API 26` app is working fine WordPress post is loading fully after migrating to androidx `API 29` post content is loading only 1-3 lines in some post & in another post 10 lines. what can be the cause for this?, Contents are not getting loaded fully. After migrating to androidX post were not getting loaded I was getting an error `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` so I added  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` after this post were getting loaded but not fully.

This is my activity post where my selected Wordpress blog post loads

**activity_post_details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_250dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imgBtnShare"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/content_post_details" />
            <include layout="@layout/content_comments" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_new_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <include layout="@layout/view_common_loader" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my layout of content post
**content_post_details.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lyt_post_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/li_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_8dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/author_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_30dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_author" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_date_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_30dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_8dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/post_author"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_calendar" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.7dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/li_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_15dp"
        android:background="@color/toolbar_boarder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewDivider"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="This is sample text do yoy know that it supports multi-line" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java file which handles Post details.

**PostdetailsActivity.java**

```
package ak.wp.meto.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import ak.wp.meto.R;
import ak.wp.meto.adapters.CommentsAdapter;
import ak.wp.meto.api.http.ApiUtils;
import ak.wp.meto.api.models.posts.post.CommentsAndReplies;
import ak.wp.meto.api.models.posts.post.PostDetails;
import ak.wp.meto.api.params.HttpParams;
import ak.wp.meto.data.constant.AppConstant;
import ak.wp.meto.data.sqlite.FavouriteDbController;
import ak.wp.meto.fragment.WriteACommentFragment;
import ak.wp.meto.listeners.ListItemClickListener;
import ak.wp.meto.models.FavouriteModel;
import ak.wp.meto.utility.ActivityUtils;
import ak.wp.meto.utility.AppUtils;
import ak.wp.meto.utility.TtsEngine;
import ak.wp.meto.webengine.WebEngine;
import ak.wp.meto.webengine.WebListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class PostDetailsActivity extends BaseActivity implements WriteACommentFragment.OnCompleteListener {
    // Variables
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;
    // init views
    private RelativeLayout lytPostDetailsView, lytCommentDetails;
    private int clickedPostId;
    private ImageView imgPost;
    private TextView tvPostTitle, tvPostAuthor, tvPostDate, tvCommnentList;
    private WebView webView;
    private FloatingActionButton fabWriteAComment;
    private ImageButton imgBtnSpeaker, imgBtnFav, imgBtnShare;
    private PostDetails model = null;
    // Favourites view
    private List<FavouriteModel> favouriteList;
    private FavouriteDbController favouriteDbController;
    private boolean isFavourite = false;
    // Comments view
    private List<CommentsAndReplies> commentList;
    private List<CommentsAndReplies> zeroParentComments;
    List<CommentsAndReplies> onlyThreeComments;
    private int mPerPage = 5;
    private RecyclerView rvComments;
    private CommentsAdapter commentsAdapter = null;
    // Text to speech
    private TtsEngine ttsEngine;
    private boolean isTtsPlaying = false;
    private String ttsText;    
    private WebEngine webEngine;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initVar();
        initView();
        initFunctionality();
        initListener();
    }

    private void initVar() {
        mActivity = PostDetailsActivity.this;
        mContext = mActivity.getApplicationContext();
            favouriteList = new ArrayList<>();
            commentList = new ArrayList<>();
        zeroParentComments = new ArrayList<>();
        onlyThreeComments = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            clickedPostId = getIntent().getIntExtra(AppConstant.BUNDLE_KEY_POST_ID, 0);
        }
    }

    private void initView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_details);
        lytPostDetailsView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_post_details);
        lytCommentDetails = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_comment_list);    
        imgPost = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.post_img);
        tvPostTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        tvPostAuthor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        tvPostDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_text);
        imgBtnSpeaker = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSpeaker);
        imgBtnFav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFavourite);
        imgBtnShare = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnShare);

        initWebEngine();

        tvCommnentList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
        fabWriteAComment = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_new_comment);

        rvComments = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvComments);
        rvComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));    
        initLoader();    
        initToolbar();
        enableBackButton();    
    }

    public void initWebEngine() {    
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);    
        webEngine = new WebEngine(webView, mActivity);
        webEngine.initWebView();        
        webEngine.initListeners(new WebListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                initLoader();
            }    
            @Override
            public void onLoaded() {
                hideLoader();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(int progress) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNetworkError() {
                showEmptyView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageTitle(String title) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void initFunctionality() {    
        favouriteDbController = new FavouriteDbController(mContext);
        favouriteList.addAll(favouriteDbController.getAllData());
        for (int i = 0; i < favouriteList.size(); i++) {
            if (favouriteList.get(i).getPostId() == clickedPostId) {
                isFavourite = true;
                break;
            }
        }    
        ttsEngine = new TtsEngine(mActivity);    
        commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(mActivity, (ArrayList) commentList, (ArrayList) onlyThreeComments);
        rvComments.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);    
        showLoader();
        loadPostDetails();    
    }

    public void setFavImage() {
        if (isFavourite) {
            imgBtnFav.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.ic_book));
        } else {
            imgBtnFav.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mActivity, R.drawable.ic_un_book));
        }
    }

    public void initListener() {

        imgBtnSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (model != null) {
                    toggleTtsPlay();
                }
            }
        });

        imgBtnFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (model != null) {
                    isFavourite = !isFavourite;
                    if (isFavourite) {
                        String imgUrl = null;
                        if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().size() >= 1) {
                            imgUrl = model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl();
                        }
                        favouriteDbController.insertData(
                                model.getID().intValue(),
                                imgUrl,
                                model.getTitle().getRendered(),
                                model.getOldDate(),
                                model.getEmbedded().getWpTerms().get(0).get(0).getName()
                        );
                    } else {
                        favouriteDbController.deleteFav(clickedPostId);
                    }
                    setFavImage();
                }
            }
        });

        imgBtnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (model != null) {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, model.getPageUrl());
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
                }
            }
        });

        commentsAdapter.setItemClickListener(new ListItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View view) {
                int id = view.getId();
                CommentsAndReplies clickedComment = zeroParentComments.get(position);
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.list_item:
                        ActivityUtils.getInstance().invokeCommentDetails(mActivity, CommentDetailsActivity.class, (ArrayList) commentList, clickedPostId, clickedComment, false, false);
                        break;
                    case R.id.reply_text:
                        ActivityUtils.getInstance().invokeCommentDetails(mActivity, CommentDetailsActivity.class, (ArrayList) commentList, clickedPostId, clickedComment, true, false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        tvCommnentList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityUtils.getInstance().invokeCommentList(mActivity,
                        CommentListActivity.class,
                        (ArrayList) commentList,
                        (ArrayList) zeroParentComments,
                        clickedPostId,
                        false);
            }
        });

        fabWriteAComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                WriteACommentFragment dialog = WriteACommentFragment.newInstance(clickedPostId, AppConstant.THIS_IS_COMMENT);
                dialog.show(manager, AppConstant.BUNDLE_KEY_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadPostDetails() {
        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().getPostDetails(clickedPostId).enqueue(new Callback<PostDetails>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PostDetails> call, Response<PostDetails> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // bind data
                    model = response.body();
                    PostDetails m = model;
                    // visible parent view
                    lytPostDetailsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // visible comments button
                    fabWriteAComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    loadCommentsAndReplies(model.getLinks().getRepliesList().get(0).getHref());    
                    setFavImage();        
                    tvPostTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(model.getTitle().getRendered()));    
                    String imgUrl = null;
                    if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().size() > 0) {
                        if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails() != null) {
                            if (model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl() != null) {
                                imgUrl = model.getEmbedded().getWpFeaturedMedias().get(0).getMediaDetails().getSizes().getFullSize().getSourceUrl();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (imgUrl != null) {
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(imgUrl)
                                .into(imgPost);
                    }

                    String author = null;
                    if (model.getEmbedded().getAuthors().size() >= 1) {
                        author = model.getEmbedded().getAuthors().get(0).getName();
                    }

                    if (author == null) {
                        author = getString(R.string.admin);
                    }
                    tvPostAuthor.setText(Html.fromHtml(author));

                    String oldDate = model.getOldDate();
                    String newDate = AppUtils.getFormattedDate(oldDate);

                    if (newDate != null) {
                        tvPostDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(newDate));
                    }

                    String contentText = model.getContent().getRendered();

                    ttsText = new StringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(model.getTitle().getRendered())).append(AppConstant.DOT).append(Html.fromHtml(model.getContent().getRendered())).toString();    
                    //webView.loadData(contentText, "text/html", "UTF-8");    
                    contentText = new StringBuilder().append(AppConstant.CSS_PROPERTIES).append(contentText).toString();
                    webEngine.loadHtml(contentText);

                } else {
                    showEmptyView();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PostDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                // hide common loader
                hideLoader();
                // show empty view
                showEmptyView();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadCommentsAndReplies(final String commentsAndRepliesLink) {

        ApiUtils.getApiInterface().getCommentsAndReplies(commentsAndRepliesLink, mPerPage).enqueue(new Callback<List<CommentsAndReplies>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CommentsAndReplies>> call, Response<List<CommentsAndReplies>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {    
                    int totalItems = Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get(HttpParams.HEADER_TOTAL_ITEM));
                    int totalPages = Integer.parseInt(response.headers().get(HttpParams.HEADER_TOTAL_PAGE));    

                    if (totalPages > 1) {
                        mPerPage = mPerPage * totalPages;
                        loadCommentsAndReplies(commentsAndRepliesLink);

                    } else {
                        if (!commentList.isEmpty() || !zeroParentComments.isEmpty() || !onlyThreeComments.isEmpty()) {
                            commentList.clear();
                            zeroParentComments.clear();
                            onlyThreeComments.clear();
                        }

                        commentList.addAll(response.body());    
                        lytCommentDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                        if (commentList.size() > 0) {
                            for (CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies : commentList) {
                                if (commentsAndReplies.getParent().intValue() == 0) {
                                    zeroParentComments.add(commentsAndReplies);
                                }
                            }

                            if (zeroParentComments.size() >= 3) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                    onlyThreeComments.add(zeroParentComments.get(i));
                                }
                            } else {
                                for (CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies : zeroParentComments) {
                                    onlyThreeComments.add(commentsAndReplies);
                                }
                            }
                            commentsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            tvCommnentList.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.all_comment), commentList.size()));
                            tvCommnentList.setClickable(true);

                        } else {
                            tvCommnentList.setClickable(false);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CommentsAndReplies>> call, Throwable t) {
                showEmptyView();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Boolean isCommentSuccessful, CommentsAndReplies commentsAndReplies) {
        if (isCommentSuccessful) {
            loadCommentsAndReplies(model.getLinks().getRepliesList().get(0).getHref());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == AppConstant.REQUEST_CODE_COMMENT) {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            boolean isCommentSuccessful = CommentListActivity.wasCommentSuccessful(data);
            if (isCommentSuccessful) {
                loadCommentsAndReplies(model.getLinks().getRepliesList().get(0).getHref());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also find build.gradle
**build.gradle(app level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ak.wp.meto"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
compile 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
compile 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
//retrofit, gson
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
//glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
//circular imageview
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Comment: I found using www.jsoneditoronline.org post is unable to compile  "&#8211;" in JSON data so post stops loading after this. In all posts, this is the cause but only in API 29 in other API it works fine.

Comment: the title should say "WebView having problem with &..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My temporary solution for this problem is I removed apostrophe, semi-colon, quotes, hyphen from my site.
Now it's working fine post are loading fully.
In JSON data hyphen is encoded as – 
In webview only "&" is shown after this remaining lines are gone. So I managed to remove special characters.

Comment: same on API 29, it's the question now if this is a WebView bug or what changed, we are also using & etc. in  a text we load and saw the issue now.

Comment: I'm using JSON API to fetch post from wordpress site. In JSON data apostrophe is encoded as &#8211;  this is decoded well upto android API28 the only problem is with android API 29 which not able to decode  &#8211 and gives output as only & after this post is not loaded. I think its webview bug. its working pretty good in all android version only problem with androidX

Comment: Actually it is not a bug as I found out, I found some posts last week but I don't remember anymore where, where a Googler explained that the load method, as already noted in its documentation, always requested html escaped characters, with the only difference that before API 29 they were not being strict about this and now they need to to be able to fix something else.

Comment: For more info check this thread: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/298

Comment: That means these encoding must be replaced by html.replace(&#8211; ," ' ");

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you don't want to replace it by " ", you want to replace it by the html-encoded version of each special char.

Comment: You should research more about html encoding, percentage escaping, maybe try Html.escapeHtml or TextUtils.htmlEncode, you need the html escaped version of the reserved chars.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this without removing the characters??

Comment: No, I tried in other ways of escaping & replacing html entities but that doesn't work for me. Removed characters from blog which was creating this problem & it worked. I'm stuck with my temporary solution

Comment: Have you applied loading CSS  from the URL used in the WordPress site?

Comment: @manismku Yes i have applied CSS from URL used in my site

Answer (score 0):

Replace your string with that special Characters`String contentText = model.getContent().replace("&#8217;","'");`